# Ration wise output by PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am stuck and could not found any solutions from web  and I am not sure how to construct the coding through PHP/Javascript and MySql.
The thing is that, I have a Table (Table-1) with

Table-1

```
Colour  Barcode Quantity
Blue    123456  25
Red     234859  35
Black   238402  60
Yellow  238492  50
```

Now I want an output of 4 colours on a page based on quantity ration MAX two rows X 4 colour format.

Example:

First Page (say):

```
Blue    Red Black   Black
Black   Black   Yellow  Yellow
```

Second Page (say):

```
Blue    Red Black   Black
Black   Yellow  Yellow  Yellow
```

And so on.

This is I am trying to achieve from a long time but could not get from where to start because I am not very good a PHP and Java script. Any help will be kind enough to complete my project
Thanks
Sagor

Comment: So you want a representative word cloud type thing

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking. Could you please try explaining again, from the beginning, in detail?

Comment: I need the output all the colours in every page till MAX qty of a colour. in a page MAX result display need to be 8. another thing is, small quantity of a colour (Blue Colour QTY) can exceed from his original QTY to meet the with MAX QTY output (Black Colour QTY).